# How to inherit access to see all projects belonging to a GCP organization?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I'm currently listed as an admin on the Google Workspace, but for some reason, there still seem to be certain operations that I can't do, like create a folder to organize projects. We're using terraform to generate some projects, and the generated projects only give access to those directly specified in the permissions.

I see inherited permissions / access referenced on the website. How would we set it up so that I, and a few other people always inherit access to see every project that's created for the organization?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I see inherited permissions / access referenced on the website. How
> would we set it up so that I, and a few other people always inherit
> access to see every project that's created for the organization?

Permissions are inherited. If you want access to all projects in an organization including future projects, grant the identities roles at the organization level.

For example, to grant the ability to view all folders projects in an organization, the appropriate role is **roles/resourcemanager.organizationViewer**. The next level up which allows the identity to browse the folders, projects and IAM policies is **roles/browser**.

To grant a role to an identity:

```
gcloud RESOURCE_TYPE add-iam-policy-binding RESOURCE_ID \
  --member=PRINCIPAL_TYPE:ID \
  --role=ROLE_ID
```

- **RESOURCE_TYPE**: projects, folders or organizations
- **RESOUOURCE_ID**: PROJECT_ID, FOLDER_ID, or ORGANIZATION_ID to match  -  -
- **PRINCIPAL_TYPE**: common values are serviceAccount, group or user
- **ID**: email address of the identity. Example john@gmail.com
- **ROLE_ID**: role to grant. Example roles/resourcemanager.organizationViewer

Example command: (replace $ORG_ID with the Organization ID)

```
gcloud organizations add-iam-policy-binding $ORG_ID \
  --member=user:john@gmail.com \
  --role=roles/resourcemanager.organizationViewer
```

[Access control for organizations using IAM](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-org)

You can accomplish the above using the Google Cloud Console GUI and via SDKs and APIs.

Comment: what role should I request if I just want default admin access to everything. I'm a little surprised by being a workspace admin, that I don't have that.

Comment: 1) Google Workspace and Google Cloud are managed independently. 2) There is no single role that grants **admin** which means all rights to all services and resources. The closest would be **Owner** plus **Organization Admin**.